# Como converter uma data para timestamp em python?

Tags: python

Tenho uma determinada data em uma variável nesse formato `d/m/Y`. Veja:

```
strDate = "29/03/2017"
```

Como converter essa data para *timestamp* em Python?

Comment: O timestamp possui diversos formatos: ISO-8601, rfc-2822, rfc-3339, Norte Americano, Europeu, Unix epoch, POSIX time, big-endian e ainda formatos Personalizados: http://brito.blog.incolume.com.br/2017/08/timestamp.html - O mais conveniente é converter a string de data, em objetos de data. Daí então formate a apresentação como quiser. - Há um exemplo no pt.stackoverflow.com com três formas de solução deste problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224598/62736 em [execução aqui](https://repl.it/JoBD/0). As soluções apresentam o uso dos pacotes datetime, time, e arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> s = "01/12/2011"
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
1322697600.0
```

Iria converter estes dados "01/12/2011" -> 1322697600

Pode tentar este forma "simplificada" também:

```
>>> int(datetime.datetime.strptime('01/12/2011', '%d/%m/%Y').strftime("%s"))
```