# Como coverter string para objeto timestamp?

Tags: python

Como posso transformar uma string contendo uma data, exemplo: `'Thu Jul 27 13:54:22 2017'`, em um objeto de datetime, ou time?

Answer (score 0):

```
def execute01():
    ''' Converte string para objeto time'''
    import time
    str_date = 'Thu Jul 27 13:54:22 2017'
    obj_date = time.strptime(str_date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

    return time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d', obj_date)

def execute02():
    ''' Converte string para objeto datetime'''
    import datetime
    str_date = 'Thu Jul 27 13:54:22 2017'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

def execute03():
    ''' Converte string para objeto arrow'''
    import arrow
    str_date = 'Thu Jul 27 13:54:22 2017'
    return arrow.get(str_date, 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss YYYY').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Em execução no https://repl.it/JoBD/0

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer? Esta é a resposta correta para a sua pergunta?

Comment: @Francisco o site permite que o usuário pergunta e responda ao mesmo tempo. Não há problemas.

Comment: Porém eu acho que poderia melhorar a explicação.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Eu sei disso, mas não sei se era isso que ele estava tentando fazer, imaginei que ele quisesse mostrar o código atual na pergunta.

Comment: aceito todas as melhorias!!!! :D

Comment: @britodfbr apenas nos confirme, sua intenção realmente foi publicar a resposta pra sua pergunta, né?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, sim.

Esta foi a resposta que consegui. Em transformar uma string em objeto timestamp.

Aceito toda sugestão para melhorar.

Comment: Sugestão oferecida, mais simples, mais enxuta, mais "friendly". :-)

Comment: @sidom, muito grato!!!
implementada a sugestão. :D

Answer (score 0):

### [Arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

`pip install arrow`

```
import datetime
timestamp = time.localtime()
str_time = arrow.get(timestamp).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ')
print (str_time)
```

**Saida:**

```
'27-07-2017 15:39:20 +00:00'
```

> Edição:
>  
>   Faltou a conversão de String para TS.

```
ts = arrow.get('27-07-2017 15:39:20', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')
print (ts)
```

**Saida:**

```
2017-07-27T15:39:20+00:00
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JleY/2)*

* Lembrando que localtime do repl.it é diferente do nosso.

Comment: e quando o timestamp é predefinido tipo **Thu Jul 27 13:54:22 2017**?

Comment: Olha na [documentação](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), é só mudar o formato, veja o Humanize, tem ainda mais opcoes.